# Confirming a dialogue box on a condition and with dynamic text in openerp

Tags: odoo

I found that the below pops me up a confirmation dialogue on button press action in openerp

```
<button name="action_button_confirm" states="draft" string="Confirm Sale" 
type="object" groups="base.group_user" confirm="Do you confirm this sale?"/>
```

I would like the confirm text to be displayed only if one of the products in the orderlines is service and the text should be

```
Do you like to confirm sale with service "AC Service"?
```

Where Ac Services is the service product name (i.e dynamic text based on the orderlines). Kindly suggest me a way to do this. Thanks

Comment: it's little bit tricky, you can achieve this by returning the action from OE methods, I have done this kind of confirmation message in past,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a wizard for alert on a condition and that does a good job to me. For people with similar prob i am placing my idea below

**My New Wizard class**

```
class sale_order_confirm(osv.osv):
    _name = "sale.order.confirm"
    _description = "Sales Order Confirm"
    def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time.'
        wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
        wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'sale.order', ids[0], 'order_confirm', cr)

        # redisplay the record as a sales order
        view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'sale', 'view_order_form')
        view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False,
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': _('Sales Order'),
            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'res_id': ids[0],
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'view_id': view_id,
            'target': 'current',
            'nodestroy': True,
        }
sale_order_confirm()
```

**My view record**

```
<record id="view_cancel_order" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Cancel Repair</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order.confirm</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Confirm Sale Order" version="7.0">
                    <group>
                        <label string="This Sale Order will be confirmed with service Product. Agree?"/>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="action_confirm" string="Yes" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                        or
                        <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel" />
                    </footer>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
```

I've changed my action_button_confirm function in the sale_order.py slightly

```
def action_button_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        assert len(ids) == 1, 'This option should only be used for a single id at a time.'
        is_optional_item_exists = False    # here i can check for wt ever condition and this variable will have the resul
        so_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
        if so_obj:
            for line in so_obj[0].order_line:
                print line.name
                if line.is_optional_item:
                     is_optional_item_exists = True

        if(is_optional_item_exists):
            return {
                'name': 'Order Confirmation',
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_model': 'sale.order.confirm',
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'nodestroy': True,
                'target': 'new',
                }
        else:
            wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
            wf_service.trg_validate(uid, 'sale.order', ids[0], 'order_confirm', cr)

            # redisplay the record as a sales order
            view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'sale', 'view_order_form')
            view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False,
            return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'name': _('Sales Order'),
                'res_model': 'sale.order',
                'res_id': ids[0],
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'view_id': view_id,
                'target': 'current',
                'nodestroy': True,
            }
```

Thanks All and Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to customize this then AFAIK you will need to use a wizard.

Extend the form and change the button name to a method that determines if you need to show the wizard (return a dictionary that contains a window action), or just directly call the existing action_button_confirm method.  The wizard can then call the action button confirm if the user clicks OK.

It is certainly do-able but a bit of mucking around for a warning that most users ignore anyway though.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your answer. Unfortunately i've completed the job before your answer could arrive. However this is the path i've chosen earlier. so will upvote it for other people. Thanks a lot for your support also check my answer.